# wait for element

Tags: powershell, browser, automation

I'm sure you've come across that you needed to wait for a site to load, and you were using

```
While ($browser.Busy -or $browser.ReadyState -ne 4) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
}
```

or similar. But it occurs many times that despite these conditions are satisfied, the page still loads. How can I wait for a specific element found by `getElementsByClassName()` to be loaded? If it's not there, I get an error and I couldn't check if it was `-eq $null`, since I couldn't reference it. I'd need something similar to `Test-Path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the elements to a variable and then on that variable do something like the following

```
while (($elementVariable -match "element") -eq False)
{
Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: I called directly <code>Select-Object -First 1</code>, and it wasn't the best idea then...

Comment: Sorry explain? It's a little late and I'm not sure I understand :')

Comment: I'm afraid that we are still lacking something. If I do &a = &browser.Document.Body.getElementsByClassName("b"), and the element is still not yet loaded, I get an error.

Comment: Have you tried the -ErrorAction parameter? Set it to silently continue it should set the variable to $Null and then it will still match the if statement